# Get TextCtrl value using ID

Tags: python, wxpython

This is how I am initializing  multiple `TextCtrls` in a `ScrollView` like usual, am in a loop so I can only keep track of the ids.

```
for value in data:
  voteheadcode = value[0]
  self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.votehead_ScrollView, int(voteheadcode), wx.EmptyString, 
  wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(400, -1), 0)
  horizontal_Scroll_BoxSizer.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
```

How can I get value entered using only id entered? In this case `voteheadcode`, normally we would

```
self.text.GetValue()
```

but this isn't workable here, I would like to get TextValue using only id.

Comment: `Bind` it to an `event`, then value will be available within the event. Otherwise, you're going to have to track them within a `list` or something similar. Taking the easy route for creation can often bite back, when it comes to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing this you can store each wx.TextCtrl in a list and then access the list's items to get the value:

```
self.text = []
for value in data:
  voteheadcode = value[0]
  self.text.append(wx.TextCtrl(self.votehead_ScrollView, int(voteheadcode), wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(400, -1), 0))
  horizontal_Scroll_BoxSizer.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
```

so then you can do:

```
self.text["the item you want's index"].GetValue()
```

or instead when you are creating them you can bind them like this:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnEnterText)

def OnEnterTex(self, event):

    control_id = event.GetId()
    control = wx.FindItemById(control_id, self)
    value = control.GetValue()
```

So then you can store the value where you want or print it